# Wrong image retrived from Parse, Asynchronous

Tags: image, swift, parse-platform

Folks. I got a problem with parse, i got an image from Parse, but images are wrong, sometimes appear the same image, other, appear wrong images, and I don't know what's happening, somebody help me! I'm a newbie in Parse and Swift. Thanks!

import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts
import Bolts
import Parse

class LojasViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

```
var ParseData = [PFObject]()
var dataObjects = [NSData]()
var photoArray: Array<UIImage> = []
var ImagemCelula = UIImage()


@IBOutlet weak var saloesTableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    GetParse()


}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // Refresh the table to ensure any data changes are displayed
    saloesTableView.reloadData()
}




// Retrieve from Parse
func GetParse() {

    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"Saloes")
    query.orderByAscending("nome")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if let object = objects as? [PFObject] {
                self.ParseData = object

                println(self.ParseData.count)
                println(self.ParseData)
                self.saloesTableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
    }
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// Esconde statusBar
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}


@IBAction func voltarButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}





// MARK: - Table view data source ____________________________________

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int
{
    return 1
}




func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return ParseData.count
}




func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell?
{
    let cell:SaloesTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! SaloesTableViewCell

    cell.nomeSalao.text = ParseData[indexPath!.row]["nome"] as? String

    for object in ParseData {
        let ImageFile = object["imagemCelula"] as! PFFile
        ImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if let imageData = imageData where error == nil
            {

                self.ImagemCelula = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                cell.imagemSalao.image = self.ImagemCelula
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must create a new array, for example:

```
    var images = [NSData]()
```

or PFFile, UIImage etc...

```
    var query = PFUser.query()
    query!.whereKey("yourWherekey", equalTo: "your where value")
    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{

        (results: [AnyObject]?, error) -> Void in

        if results != nil {

            for result in results!
            {
                self.images.append(result["image"] as! NSData)

                self.tableView.reloadData() // important


            }

        }
    }
```

Append to images to Images Array.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellA", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = "TEST STRING"
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: images[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

And connect with indexPath.row. I coded with NSData if you want you can code with PFFile

Comment: Hi Rys! Sorry for late. So! I tryed to understand this relationship with Parse, but I confess, not easy, at least to me, rsss I will put my entire code to try and help me!